# Qt design issue with QTableWidget

Tags: qt, textures, qtablewidget

At the moment, I am programming a little map editor for my 2D-RPG game.
All functions are successfully implemented, but my problem is, that the textures for each cell in my `QTableWidget` aren't stretched to the full size of 32x32. I have already changed the `sizeHint` settings, but it doesn't work.
Here a little [picture](http://s14.directupload.net/images/131231/acqnwyss.png) about my problem.

As you can see, in each cell are a white background and the textures aren't fully stretched. Actually I load the textures over the `setIcon` function, maybe an other way exists to load images in a cell? How can I fix it, for stretching to the full size of 32x32?

Answer (score 0):

Try to style the icon or see where its padding/margin gets defined.